# Scala: some questions on flatMap and map

Tags: scala, scala-collections

I have a piece of Scala codes here: https://scastie.scala-lang.org/1ey5T9lWQVOAozLoGVJthw

```
val days = List((1, (2, "a")), (1, (3, "b")), (1, (1, "c")), (2, (1, "aa")), (2, (2, "bb")))

println(days)

println(days.groupBy(_._1))
val r = days.groupBy(_._1).map(t => {
  println(s"t = $t, t._1 = ${t._1} t._2 = ${t._2} t._2.map(_._2) = ${t._2.map(_._2).toMap}")
  t._1 -> t._2.map(_._2).toMap
})


println(s"r = $r")

val rr = r.flatMap {
  case (k, v) => Some(k, v)
}

println(rr)

val rrr = r.map {
  case (k, v) => Some(k, v)
}

println(rrr)
```

The output after run the program:

```
List((1,(2,a)), (1,(3,b)), (1,(1,c)), (2,(1,aa)), (2,(2,bb)))
Map(2 -> List((2,(1,aa)), (2,(2,bb))), 1 -> List((1,(2,a)), (1,(3,b)), (1,(1,c))))
t = (2,List((2,(1,aa)), (2,(2,bb)))), t._1 = 2 t._2 = List((2,(1,aa)), (2,(2,bb))) t._2.map(_._2) = Map(1 -> aa, 2 -> bb)
t = (1,List((1,(2,a)), (1,(3,b)), (1,(1,c)))), t._1 = 1 t._2 = List((1,(2,a)), (1,(3,b)), (1,(1,c))) t._2.map(_._2) = Map(2 -> a, 3 -> b, 1 -> c)
r = Map(2 -> Map(1 -> aa, 2 -> bb), 1 -> Map(2 -> a, 3 -> b, 1 -> c))
Map(2 -> Map(1 -> aa, 2 -> bb), 1 -> Map(2 -> a, 3 -> b, 1 -> c))
List(Some((2,Map(1 -> aa, 2 -> bb))), Some((1,Map(2 -> a, 3 -> b, 1 -> c))))
```

I have some questions:

1, why `rr` and `rrr` are different?

(1) Why `rr` is a `Map`, but `rrr` is a `List`?
I understand `rrr` is a `List`. `map` will operate on each key-value pair, and finally return a `List`. Am I right? But why `flatMap` return a `Map`?

(2) why `Some` in `rrr`? `Some` used to filter out `None`?

2, In `flatMap`, `Some(k, v)` will be resolved into `k->v`?

3, In `flatMap`, `Some(a -> (b -> c))` will be resolved into `(a, (b, c))`?

As for 2 and 3, I am confused why tuple and Map messed together? I may be wrong.

I am new to Scala. Even I read some tutorials, I still have too many confusions. Most tutorials gave examples on `flatMap` of `List`, `Seq`.

Any help welcomed. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The result type of most of the collection methods like `map`, `flatMap`, etc. depends on the result type of the function that we pass to it.

This is determined by the [`CanBuildFrom`](https://scala-lang.org/blog/2017/05/30/tribulations-canbuildfrom.html) implicit values.

Given that, there is a `CanBuildFrom` instance for `Map` types based on `Tuple2`. In other words, if you return a `Tuple2` from the function passed to `map` of a `Map` then the result is also a `Map`, but if you return something other than `Tuple2` the `map` function chooses the next specific `CanBuildFrom` which is based on `Iterable`.

In the case of `rr`, `flatMap` basically calls `flatten` and then `map`. During the `flatten` operation, the `Option[Tuple2[A, B]]` is flattend to just `Tuple2[A, B]` and so `Tuple2` is passed to `map` function and so the result is a `Map`.

In the case of `rrr`, the result is not a `Tuple2`, but rather `Option[Tuple2[A, B]]`, so it cannot use the `CanBuildFrom` defined by the `Map` at [`GenMapFactory.scala`](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.12.3/src/library/scala/collection/generic/GenMapFactory.scala#L58).

To add more to that, try the below code and the result will be a `Map`

```
val r3 = r.map {
  case (k, v) => (k, v)
}

println(r3) //r3 is a Map not a List
```

Comment: In flatMap, Some(a -> (b -> c)) will be resolved into (a, (b, c))?

Comment: @BAE The `(x -> y)` is just alternative syntax for `(x, y)`. It holds everywhere, it's not specific to `flatMap` in any way.